# HTML 5 video, how to stop it when navigating to another link

Tags: jquery, html, video

I got a html consisting of a left menu (containing video links) and a content area (where the video is being played).

When I click on e.g video 1 it plays fine but if I click on e.g video 2 while watching video 1 then video 1 will keep playing. How can I check and stop video's which are playing while clicking a link in my left menu?

simplified code snippet:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li id="link1"><a href="#">Video 1</a></li>
                <li id="link2"><a href="#">Video 2</a></li>
                <li id="link3"><a href="#">Video 3</a></li>               
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div id="video1" class="content">
                <h1>Video 1</h1>
                <video src="test1.mp4" width="600" height="400" controls>
                    <p>Please use a modern browser to view this video.</p>
                </video>
            </div>
            <div id="video2" class="content">
                <h1>Video 2</h1>        
                <video src="test2.mp4" width="600" height="400" controls>
                    <p>Please use a modern browser to view this video.</p>
                </video>        
            </div>
            <div id="video3" class="content">        
                <h1>Video 3</h1>
                <video src="test3.mp4" width="600" height="400" controls>
                    <p>Please use a modern browser to view this video.</p>
                </video>        
            </div>                 
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#menu a').click(function(){
             $('.main div').hide();
             var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
             $('.main div').eq(tmp_div).show();
          });
         $('.main div').hide(); 
    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you:

```
    $('#menu a').click(function(){
         $('.main div').hide();
         var videos = $('.main div').find('video');
         videos.each(function(){
            $(this)[0].pause(); // This pause all videos
         });
         var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
         $('.main div').eq(tmp_div).show();             
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Every action in a `<video>` in Html5 triggers some events. Every time you press the "play" button, pause etc. So I recommend to use some Javascript to handle this events when occur. You can improve the code above by adding some actions.
When you hide the video use the `video.pause();` property. 
I found some documentation in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924823(v=vs.85).aspx) that can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Details are commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
      <ul id="menu">

        <!---Each link has the class .lnk and href value added-->

        <li id="link1"><a href="#v1" class='lnk'>Video 1</a></li>
        <li id="link2"><a href="#v2" class='lnk'>Video 2</a></li>
        <li id="link3"><a href="#v3" class='lnk'>Video 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div id="video1" class="content">

        <!--Each video has an id that corresponds to a .lnk href-->

        <h1>Video 1</h1>
        <video id='v1' src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" width="240" height="160" controls>
                    <p>Please use a modern browser to view this video.</p>
                </video>
      </div>
      <div id="video2" class="content">
        <h1>Video 2</h1>
        <video id='v2' src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" width="240" height="160" controls>
                    <p>Please use a modern browser to view this video.</p>
                </video>
      </div>
      <div id="video3" class="content">
        <h1>Video 3</h1>
        <video id='v3' src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" width="240" height="160" controls>
                    <p>Please use a modern browser to view this video.</p>
                </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    /* This function will play the video that matches
            || clicked .lnk and pause any video playing.
            */ // Delegate click event to all .lnk
    $('.lnk').on('click', function() {

      // Store the clicked .lnk href in var tgt
      var tgt = $(this).attr('href');

      // Collect all video elements into a NodeList
      var vids = document.querySelectorAll('video');

      /* Turn the NodeList into an array, then...
      || forEach video, find it's id then pause it
      */
      Array.from(vids).forEach(function(obj, idx) {
        var ID = obj.id;
        document.getElementById(ID).pause();
      });

      // Hide all .content
      $('.content').hide();

      // Reference the video that matches the .lnk clicked
      var vid = $(tgt)[0];

      // Find vid's parent .content and show() it
      $(tgt).parent('.content').show();

      // Play the video
      vid.play();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```